# Custom Build System not displayed when set to Automatic

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, build-system

I wrote a custom build system to compile and run a cpp file, as below:

```
{
    "cmd": [
        "clang++",
        "-o",
        "$file_base_name.out",
        "$file",
        "&&",
        "./$file_base_name.out"
    ],
    "selector": "source.cpp",
    "quiet": true
}
```

It is not being shown in the automatic build systems, which I assume is due to the `selector` not being recognized. What do I need to change?

Comment: It says `clang: error: no such file or directory: '&&'` when I manually set the build system, which technically should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the `scope` selector that you're using is not correct here; the `scope` of C++ files is `source.c++` and not `source.cpp`. You can use `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name` from the menu (or the associated key) while you're editing a file to see the full scope at the current cursor location. For a build system the first line in the scope popup is the one you want to use.

There's another issue with your build (which you have alluded to in the comments) that the build doesn't work as expected. The reason for that is that you're using `cmd` to execute your build, but you're use shell constructs (the `&&`).

When you specify `cmd` in a build system, you provide a list of strings; the first item is the name of the program that you want to execute (here it's `clang++`), and the remaining items are arguments to be given to the program being executed.

So in this case, you're asking Sublime to execute `clang++` directly, and one of the arguments that you're providing to it is `&&`, which it assumes is the name of a file. The intention is to try and run the program if it successfully compiles, but using `&&` is a function of your shell (e.g. `bash` or the like) and not of `clang`.

You can try adding `"shell": true` to your build, which tells Sublime that it should try to execute `cmd` through the system shell instead; that passes everything as a whole to the shell, which does know how to handle `&&`.

The other alternative is to use `shell_cmd` instead; in that case you provide a single string that represents the command line that you would enter into the terminal. In this case when you execute the build, Sublime automatically passes the value to the shell for execution.

In your case, that might look like:

```
"shell_cmd": "clang++ -o \"${file_base_name}.out\" \"$file\" && \"./${file_base_name}.out\"",
```

Apart from the value being a single string, it's also important to note that if your filenames can potentially contain spaces, you need to wrap all filename arguments in double quotes so that the shell handles things properly.

Comment: Thanks! Changing `selector` to `source.c++` did work. But I'm still having issues. I used `cmd` to be able to divide the command across lines. I included `shell: true`, but it says `clang: error: no input files'.

Comment: ```{
 "cmd": [
  "clang++",
  "$file",
  "-o",
  "$file_base_name.out",
  "&&",
  "./$file_base_name.out"
 ],
 "working_dir":"$file_path",
 "selector": "source.c++",
 "shell": true
}```

Comment: The first thought would be to make sure that the file that you're trying to build exists on disk (it won't for example if you create a brand new file and never save it); in such a case the file has no name and `$file` expands to nothing. If that's not the case, try swapping the `cmd` line with the `shell_cmd` in my answer and see if that helps any.

Comment: The file does exist. I'm weirded out right now. Guess I'll have to stick with using `shell_cmd`.

Comment: I've seen cases where using `"shell": true` doesn't always fully replicate what using `shell_cmd` does; I'm pretty sure it's a Python thing, since Sublime just uses a standard Python module to spawn sub processes.